# How to resize the size of image and prevent none images using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to re-size the size of the image to the default size of the img tag id `Picture` i declare on the css. And prevent users in uploading none images files using `jquery`.

```
#Picture img {
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
}
```

My problem is after i upload the picture it will show his original size and it also accept none image files.

current output:  http://jsfiddle.net/LvsYc/3115/

Answer (score 2):

To get the css style resize working you need to do this.  Your image has an id of Picture therefore just `#Picture` without `img` will work

```
#Picture {
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
}
```